# Continuation Passing Style Computation Expression

Tags: f#, continuation-passing, computation-expression

Can you implement CPS using computation expressions in F#?

[Brian McNamara's blog](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/catamorphisms-part-seven/) gives this solution:

```
type ContinuationBuilder() = 
  member this.Return(x) = (fun k -> k x) 
  member this.ReturnFrom(x) = x 
  member this.Bind(m,f) = (fun k -> m (fun a -> f a k)) 
  member this.Delay(f) = f() 

let cps = ContinuationBuilder()
```

Looks good. I can write `List.map` in CPS:

```
let rec mapk f xs = cps {
  match xs with
  | [] -> return []
  | x::xs ->
      let! xs = mapk f xs
      return f x::xs
}
```

But it stack overflows:

```
mapk ((+) 1) [1..1000000] id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `Delay` function in the computation builder is immediately calling the function - this means that when you call `mapk`, it will immediately run the pattern matching and then call `mapk` recursively (before passing its result to the `Bind` operation).

You can fix this by using an implementation of `Delay` that returns a function which invokes `f` only after it is given a final continuation - this way, the recursive call will just return a function (without doing more recursive calls that cause stack overflow):

```
member this.Delay(f) = (fun k -> f () k)
```

With this version of `Delay`, the your code works as expected for me.